# NSDictionary objectForKey time efficiency

Tags: objective-c, performance, time-complexity, foundation

This is kind of an extension of one of my older questions, but when you call the selector objectForKey: for the NSDictionary is that an order one operation like it should be? Returning either a value associated with that key or nothing if the key does not exist? When I implement the NSDictionary objectForKey operation it feels like its implementing at a linear time efficiency :(

Comment: Show the relevant code including the `hash` and `isEqual:` methods of the custom objects in your dictionary (assuming they are custom objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSDictionary does not make strong time complexity *guarantees*, but in practice it is O(1) as would be expected for a hashing based collection. If you're seeing >O(1) behavior, make sure your objects have good hash functions; you could be running into collisions.

Comment: how might i check my hash functions?

Comment: Override -isEqual: on your objects and add a counter of how many times it's called. If it's called many more times than the number of lookups, that indicates that many probe attempts are being made for each lookup.